# Does banning someone require any formalities?

Tags: canada, private-property

For example, to be banned from a store that the public is allowed into, does a manager speaking the words "you're banned" count as enough? Is any sort of documentation required? Does it make a difference if there's a reason and if the person is already in the store?

Answer (score 4):

### No

Once a person in control of a property has withdrawn your permission to be there, you must leave as soon as practicable or become a trespasser.

Answer (score 4):

No. All that matters is that the individual is made aware that they are banned.

The store is private property as you say. That private property gives the general public permission to enter at certain times. This permission can be withdrawn at any time, for any or no reason (barring unlawful discrimination).

I work in retail and we do have a formal procedure to ban someone. It involves a form which is filled out and signed by both parties. In theory this prevents cases like this where the individual claims not to know they are banned (as well as a paper trail). In practice I don't think we've ever used it- there's never been a case where the individual being ejected is cooperative enough to sign it. Procedure is usually the individual being told not to come back while they shout obscenities.

The same applies to being in the store and being told to leave. Once you have been told to leave you no longer have permission to be on the property.